# Distribution of Minimum Distance between repeated integers in a sequence

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions, permutations

Let $a$ be an integer sequence containing unique consecutive integers $(1, 2, ..., N)$

Let $b$ be any random permutation of $a$. For example, $(N, 1, ..., 2)$. Assume $b$ is chosen uniformly from the set of all  permutations of $a$.

Let $c$ be the sequence of $b$ appended to $a$. Using the two lines above as an example, $c=(1, 2, ..., N, N, 1, ..., 2)$

Let $D$ be the minimum distance between any two repeated elements of $c$. In the example above, since $N$ immediately follows $N$, $D=1$. If $c$ were instead $(1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1)$, $D$ would be $2$ since both twos (and threes) are two elements apart in the sequence.

Given $D$ varies with the randomly selected permutation of $b$, $D$ is a random variable. What is the distribution of $D$ as a function of $N$?

Edit:

I wrote some python code to calculate the empirical distribution up to N = 11, in case this helps identify some patterns. Here is the code and the output:

```
def mindist(alist, blist):
  min_dist = 9999999999
  for item in alist:
    b_ind = blist.index(item) + len(alist)
    delta = b_ind - alist.index(item)
    if delta < min_dist:
      min_dist = delta
  return min_dist

import itertools
for N in range(3, 11 + 1):
  distribution = {}
  print(N)
  aa = list(range(1, N + 1))
  permutations = list(itertools.permutations(aa))
  for bb in permutations:
    md = mindist(aa, list(bb))
    if md in distribution.keys():
      distribution[md] += 1
    else:
      distribution[md] = 1
  print(distribution)
  print('-'*80)
```

Output:

```
3
{3: 1, 2: 3, 1: 2}
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
4
{4: 1, 3: 7, 2: 10, 1: 6}
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
5
{5: 1, 4: 15, 3: 38, 2: 42, 1: 24}
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
6
{6: 1, 5: 31, 4: 130, 3: 222, 2: 216, 1: 120}
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
7
{7: 1, 6: 63, 5: 422, 4: 1050, 3: 1464, 2: 1320, 1: 720}
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
8
{8: 1, 7: 127, 6: 1330, 5: 4686, 4: 8856, 3: 10920, 2: 9360, 1: 5040}
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
9
{9: 1, 8: 255, 7: 4118, 6: 20202, 5: 50424, 4: 80520, 3: 91440, 2: 75600, 1: 40320}
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
10
{10: 1, 9: 511, 8: 12610, 7: 85182, 6: 276696, 5: 558120, 4: 795600, 3: 851760, 2: 685440, 1: 362880}
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
11
{11: 1, 10: 1023, 9: 38342, 8: 353850, 7: 1481784, 6: 3723720, 5: 6502320, 4: 8542800, 3: 8749440, 2: 6894720, 1: 3628800}
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: My intuition is that the distribution of $D$ will tend to $\sqrt N$ times some fixed distribution function, possibly that of a Poisson variable.

Comment: @GregMartin not Poisson: in individual cases as there is a bound, while  in the rescaled limit the distribution would presumably be continuous.  But a mode close to $\sqrt{N}$ looks plausible empirically - the mean may be around a quarter higher

Comment: https://oeis.org/A056151

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@BGM's comment pointed out a [closely related distribution](https://oeis.org/A056151) which is known in the OEIS. Basically, $P(D = k) = \frac 1{N!} T(N,N+1-k)$, where $T$ is the table defined in the OEIS page.

Now, I believe that $D/\sqrt N$ converges in distribution to a Rayleigh-distributed random variable. In other words,
$P(D > t\sqrt{N}) \to e^{-t^2/2}$. In particular, the mode should be around $\sqrt N$ and the mean should be asymptotic to $\sqrt{N\pi/2}$.

Proof :

Let us compute $P(D>k)$. We will express that event in terms of a certain construction of the random permutation $b$, which consists of choosing where $N$ goes in $b$ uniformly at random among the $N$ possible spots, then choosing where $N-1$ goes among the $N-1$ remaining spots, etc.

For $D>k$, you cannot put $N$ in the first $k$ spots. So that's a probability of $\dfrac {N-k}{N}$.
Then considering $N-1$, out of the $N-1$ possible spots (excluding where you have already put $N$), the first $k-1$ of them are forbidden (and the one where you already put $N$ can't be one of them!). So that's a probabilitiy of $\dfrac{N-k}{N-1}$.

And so on... In the end,
$$ P( D>k) = \dfrac {N-k}{N}\dfrac {N-k}{N-1}\cdots\dfrac {N-k}{N-k-1}\\
= \dfrac {(N-k)^k (N-k)!}{N!}.$$
Let us compute an asymptotic equivalent of that, assuming $N\to \infty$ and $k = o(N)$. We then have necessarily $N-k\to\infty$ also so we can use Stirling's formula in both factorials.
$$
\sim \dfrac{ (N-k)^k \sqrt{2\pi (N-k)}(\frac {N-k}e)^{N-k}}{\sqrt{2\pi N}(\frac {N}e)^{N}}\\
= \sqrt{1-k/N}\dfrac{ (N-k)^N e^k}{N^N}
\sim (1-\frac kN)^Ne^k\\
= \exp( k + N\log(1-k/N))\\
=\exp\left((k + N\left[(-k/N) + \frac 12 (-\frac kN)^2 + o((\frac kN)^3)\right]\right)\\
= \exp \left(- \frac {k^2}{2N} + o(\dfrac {k^3}{N^2})\right)$$

Plugging now $k = t\sqrt N$ we get the claimed result.

Comment: You beat me by 5 minutes :-) Well done

Comment: Thank you! Yes that happens a lot here and can be sometimes frustrating, that's why I try to first post the answer and then edit the proof in.

Comment: You can also write $P( D>k) = \prod_j (1- j/N) = \exp \sum_j \log (1 - j/N)$ and use the  Taylor expansion of $\log(1-x)$

Comment: You're perfectly right, though I believe your first equality is not exact, is it ?

Comment: Yes, I messed it up.